Building C Objects Into One Directory Without Losing the 'make' Mapping
I have this source tree:
library/
| _build/
| | Makefile
| topic_1/
| topic_2/
| ...

I'm organizing the source code (*.c, *.h) into topic folders and I currently successfully compile the object files. However they turn into _build/topic_1/*.o and _build/topic_2/*.o files, basically duplicating the library's tree into the _build folder. I'd like to put them all into just the _build folder so I don't need to run $(shell find $(LOC) -name '*.o') to get them all.
I could simply copy them and then delete, but that's inefficient and I'd like to avoid that. I want to directly compile them into the _build so that I don't need to use recursive searching, and I also want to maintain the file mapping that 'make' recognizes so it doesn't rebuild absolutely every object file on any change.
The issue I'm having is that when I create a target like %.o: if '%' doesn't contain the topic folder (just src.c), I lose information about where to find the source file. But if '%' contains the topic folder (like topic_1/src.c) and I just filter the topic directory out when writing the -o flag then 'make' doesn't find that target anymore so it reruns that target at every call.
This is all made worse because I don't want to manually write any file/directory names into the Makefile. I'm currently getting the source files with $(shell find .. -name '*.c') to avoid that. If I manually wrote down each file into the make file, then I could do this without an issue by just hard coding the mappings.
Is there a way to encode more information into a target while not affecting make's ability to find it? Or is there a way to dynamically create targets at runtime where I can hold this information (define endef maybe)?
Editted: Clarifying my goal, Removed LIB_DIRS confusion

If your directory structure when building is different than the source files, you have to satisfy both path constraints; rather then, eg c_objs := $(patsubst $(src)/%.c, $(build)/%.o, $(c_srcs)), which is probably easier to understand?

Just to note that putting all objects into a single directory is fine but IF and ONLY IF you can guarantee that no source files in different directories will have the same name; for example you can't have foo/impl.c and also bar/impl.c.
Unfortunately your examples are not sufficient for us to provide a full solution.  Specifically, you don't specify how you're finding or listing the source files to be compiled.
Also I don't understand why you show the Makefile in the _build directory, when it contains _build/%.o in the pattern rule... do you run make -f _build/Makefile from the root directory?
And finally, I am completely lost by the discussion of LIB_DIR and have no idea what that is attempting to do.
Anyway, the way to do what you want is using the VPATH feature of GNU Make, which will search a path for source files.  So, supposing you have a variable SRCS that contains a full set of the source files you want to compile, you can use something like:
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SRCS))

_build/%.o : %.c
        $(CC) ...

Use a prerequisite pattern for just the source file, and GNU Make will search the directories in VPATH to find that file.
